# Add element at the end of linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

How can i add an element at the end of a linked list?

This is my try but I know there are some incorrect things:

```
typedef struct node_struct{
        int data;
        struct node_struct *next;
}node;

node *end(node *p){
     node *new = malloc(sizeof(node));
     node *next;
     int value;
     printf("Insert new element: ");
     scanf("%d",&value);
     p->next = next;
     new->data = value;
     next = new->data;

     return next;

     return next;
}
```

Now this is my code but it's still doesn't work:

```
node *end(node *p){
     node *new = malloc(sizeof(node));
     node *next;
     int value;
     printf("Insert new element: ");
     scanf("%d",&value);
     p->next = next;
     new->data = value;
    while(next->next){
         next = next->next;
    }
    next->next = new;

    return new;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried searching? There are many many example implementations and explanations of linked lists out there. If you need specific help with your code then you need to provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and include what specific error or incorrect results you are getting.

Comment: For starters you are not setting `new->next`. Should be `new->next=NULL;`

Comment: I searched but i found only example in java. I just want tot add an element at the end of the linked list but i can't.

Comment: Other problems: 1. Compiler warnings are being ignored. `next=new->data` should cause compiler screaming as the types are incompatible. 2. `p` is being passed in but not used. Is `p` the existing list? You need to link the new element to the existing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to iterate to the end of the linked list before you add the new node.

```
node *end(node *p){
    // ...

    node *next = p;

    while(next->next){
        next = next->next;
    }

    ...

    next->next = new;

    return new; // Returns end of the linked list
}
```

Note that you should normally check if `p` is null, and if so return an error code, or handle the error otherwise.

Comment: Thank you i didn't understand how to iterate the list

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, this code works well, at least I think so.

```
void end(node *head){
     node *new = malloc(sizeof(node));
     node *next;
     int value;
     next = head->next;
     printf("Insert number to add at the end: ");
     scanf("%d",&value);
     new->data= value;
     while(next->next){
          next = next->next;
          }
     next->next = new;
     }
```

Comment: This will lead into a segfault when head or head->next is null.
You should do a check at the beginning of the function if head is null and you also should change the line `next = head->next;` to `next = head;`
Just test your code with `end(null);` and with a list that consists of only the head.